# Why do two different +1 buttons on the same page but for different urls show the same counts?

Tags: canonical-url, google-plus, google-plus-one, social-sharing-buttons

The following buttons *always* display the same count (which is the count of the page without the querystring) despite being different urls:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small"
  data-href="http://prodct.info/chromebooks/?toshiba-cb35"></div>

<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small"
  data-href="http://prodct.info/chromebooks/?dell-chromebook-11-4gb-i3"></div>
```

However, the state of whether I've clicked them is tracked individually.

You can see a sample page with both of these buttons on [here](http://prodct.info/temp/gplus.htm).

What's going on?

I did once have canonical tags for both of those urls that would've pointed to the same URL. but it was only up for a few hours at most; and has been gone for a few days. If this was the cause, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `og:url` tag is currently:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://prodct.info/chromebooks/" />
```

Should it not be the unique URL of the page? Be sure to test any changes with Webmaster's `Structured Data Testing Tool`

Description of og:url:

> The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID
>   in the graph.

Comment: I went to the Webmasters Structured Data tool and got `We do not detect any structured data on your site`. I can't find any info suggesting that Google+ uses this though (not would it explain why the buttons states are individual); but I'll try removing it.

Comment: Removing this doesn't appear to have made any difference.